# R package DARCH deep belief neural network cannot learn 'exclusive or' it seems

Tags: r, neural-network, deep-learning

Thank you in advance for any help. I am trying to implement a deep learning neural network to predict a number of variables (a sort of multivariate non-linear regression). As a first step I am looking at the Darch package in R and working through the code snippets in

http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/darch/darch.pdf

When I run the following code from p 10, which appears to be training on 'exclusive or', then the resultant neural network appears to be unable to learn the function. It either learns the (1,0) pattern or the (0,1) pattern as true, but not both, and sometimes additionally the (1,1) pattern, which should be false. My understanding was that these kind of networks should be able to learning almost any function, including for starters 'exclusive or': was this not resolved by the original backpropagation work, which this network utilizes in the fine tuning. I think I could be missing something, so any advice or help is very much appreciated? (I have even increased the epochs upto 10,000, but to no avail.)

```
# Generating the datasets
inputs <- matrix(c(0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1),ncol=2,byrow=TRUE)
outputs <- matrix(c(0,1,1,0),nrow=4)
# Generating the darch
darch <- newDArch(c(2,4,1),batchSize=2)
# Pre-Train the darch
darch <- preTrainDArch(darch,inputs,maxEpoch=100)
# Prepare the layers for backpropagation training for
# backpropagation training the layer functions must be
# set to the unit functions which calculates the also
# derivatives of the function result.
layers <- getLayers(darch)
for(i in length(layers):1){
    layers[[i]][[2]] <- sigmoidUnitDerivative

}
setLayers(darch) <- layers
rm(layers)
# Setting and running the Fine-Tune function
setFineTuneFunction(darch) <- backpropagation
darch <- fineTuneDArch(darch,inputs,outputs,maxEpoch=100)
# Running the darch
darch <- darch <- getExecuteFunction(darch)(darch,inputs)
outputs <- getExecOutputs(darch)
cat(outputs[[length(outputs)]])
## End(Not run)


#### Example results


> cat(outputs[[length(outputs)]])
0.02520016 0.8923063 0.1264799 0.9803244

## Different run

> cat(outputs[[length(outputs)]])
0.02702418 0.1061477 0.9833059 0.9813462
```

Comment: The network, as I understand it, is a feedforward perceptron.  When I read on page 4-19 of Hagan, Demuth, and Beale (1996) I read that "the perceptron can be used to classify input vectors that can be separated by a linear boundary.  We call such vectors linearly separable. ... Unfortunately, many problems are not linearly separable.  The classic example is the XOR gate."

Answer (score 2):

For what it's worth, the following worked for me:

```
# Generating the datasets
inputs <- matrix(c(0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1),ncol=2,byrow=TRUE)
print(inputs)

outputs <- matrix(c(0,1,1,0),nrow=4)
print(outputs)


# Generating the darch
darch <- newDArch(c(2,4,1),batchSize=4,ff=F)

# Pre-Train the darch
darch <- preTrainDArch(darch,inputs,maxEpoch=200,numCD=4)

# Prepare the layers for backpropagation training for
# backpropagation training the layer functions must be
# set to the unit functions which calculates the also
# derivatives of the function result.
layers <- getLayers(darch)
for(i in length(layers):1){
  layers[[i]][[2]] <- sigmoidUnitDerivative
}

setLayers(darch) <- layers
rm(layers)

# Setting and running the Fine-Tune function
setFineTuneFunction(darch) <- rpropagation
darch <- fineTuneDArch(darch,trainData=inputs,targetData=outputs,
                       maxEpoch=200,
                       isBin=T)

# Running the darch
darch <- darch <- getExecuteFunction(darch)(darch,inputs)
outputs2 <- getExecOutputs(darch)
cat(outputs2[[length(outputs2)]])
## End(Not run)
```

Gave the following results

```
> # Running the darch
> darch <- darch <- getExecuteFunction(darch)(darch,inputs)

> outputs2 <- getExecOutputs(darch)

> cat(outputs2[[length(outputs2)]])
1.213234e-21 1 1 1.213234e-21
> ## End(Not run)
1.213234e-21 1 1 1.213234e-21
```

So the following changes were made:

- learning was changed to resilient back-propagation from classic back-propagation
- batchsize was set to 4
- numCD was set to 4

Because I am essentially performing Voodoo (until I practice this some), I can't seem to keep the error rate below about 17%.

**EDIT:**

So I have been reading up and am trending in thinking that each unique state of the system is related to a single interior neuron.  If you have two-bit logic then there are four unique combinations of inputs so there are four unique input states.  If you want a system that can handle that then you need 4 interior nodes.  This means that for 8-bit operations you might need 256 internal nodes.

The [atari-game folks](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~vmnih/docs/dqn.pdf) had model adaptive control, so with one network they were predicting the next state of the system and with another they were determining the best control strategy given the current state AND the expected next state.

When I reran this a few thousand times the output after long training was erroneous about 18% of the time.  I really didn't like that.

Thoughts:

- If I add the right noise can I recover the effect of [simulated annealing](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SimulatedAnnealing.html) on stability?
- If I add something like hamming codes to the inputs, can I exchange space-size for stability?
- The times that the output stabilizes erroneously is when two outputs are exactly equal.  Can I build detection of that into the training algorithm and use it to update one "weight" but not the other and thus decouple the (allegedly decoupled) neurons?
- List item

Comment: `Darch` looks very complicated compared w/ `h2o`, `nnet` or others, and I don't have experience to use it. Is there any advantages of `Darch`? Very detailed answer +1

Comment: Deep learning is a headache.  Darch is deep learning.  You can get some great mileage with h2o, or with a number of tools.  Carpenters with hand-tools make beautiful work every day, without the need for power tools.  Same is true in data.  imo - if a hammer works, don't use a jackhammer.

Comment: It makes sense, sometime we don't need too rely on power tools. I will try to use Darch and to understand more details :) Thanks again!

Comment: Darch is the jack-hammer.  If you want something that isn't a bad mid-level power tool, consider a random forest.  If you are looking for a chisel, consider a logistic regression.  :)  Myself, I have done a lot of good with the 'randomForest' or even the h2o variation thereof.  It is relatively simple, and can easily handle the logic problem above.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to tune the baseline `example.xor` in darch to reliably learn the simple xor correctly.  Here is the baseline version:

```
> tmp<-mclapply(1:50, function(x) example.xor())
> table(sapply(tmp,function(x) tail(x@stats$dataErrors$class,1)))

 0 25 
30 20
```

Here is a tuned variant:

```
trainingData <- matrix(
    c(0,0,
      0,1,
      1,0,
      1,1), ncol=2, byrow=T)
trainingTargets <- matrix(c(0,1,1,0),nrow=4)

tuned.xor <- function() {
    darch(trainingData, trainingTargets,
        # These settings are different
        layers=c(2,6,1),
        darch.batchSize=4,
        darch.fineTuneFunction=function(...) rpropagation(..., weightDecay=0.0001),
        # These settings are all as in example.xor
        darch.bootstrap=F,
        darch.learnRateWeights = 1.0,
        darch.learnRateBiases = 1.0,
        darch.isBin=T,
        darch.stopClassErr=0, 
        darch.numEpochs=1000
    )
}

> tmp<-mclapply(1:50, function(x) tuned.xor())
> table(sapply(tmp,function(x) tail(x@stats$dataErrors$class,1)))

 0 
50
```